# Android Studio - ListView updates in weird way

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

My `ListView` is connected to a database online. I click on a button from the main activity that starts the activity that has the `ListView`. When I create a item in another activity and add it to the database the `ListView` still has the old items.

So for example, I click on a button in the main activity that leads me to the create item activity when I add a item into the database online. Then I go back to the main activity and I click on the button that leads to the activity with the `ListView`and then it shows all the items EXCEPT the one i just added. However, when I press the back button to back to the main activity that has the button and press the button again, the `ListView` is updated with the item that were created. I have to do this every time I want the `ListView` to show the updated items I just created.

How can this happen? Given the same `onCreate()` method is called when I press the button. Why does going and coming back update the `ListView`?

**ANSWER**: I was populating the ListView before I got a response from the server, hence, the ListView has incorrect information. The response was received by the time I went back and started the activity again. That's why now the correct information was there. To solve this I populated the the ListView after I got a response from the server.

Comment: Do you go back using a android back button or something else?

Comment: because you load listView @onCreate >> after creating new item (data) reload listView at that point OR @onResume()

Comment: I went back using a button that takes you to main activity not the android back icon.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Activity` with `ListView` is resumed it was not destroyed so it wont start afresh you have two alternatives

- Override `onResume` method and load your data there probably using network connection again in your `ListViewActivity`.
- The easy one,  Override `onBackPressed` in your add item activity and start the activity with `listView` like this:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {

      Intent intent=new Intent(this, YourActivityWithListView.class);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
  ```

Comment: The onCreate method AND the onResume is called every time I start the listView activity. I checked this putting a toast message in both methods and starting the listView activity and both appear.

Comment: Okay then check your logic somewhere else, butc `onCreate` cannot be called when resuming an activity.